# Web Api Route Attributes not matching on remote server

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We have an API, routed with Attributes, and registered first in our start up method with `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`

This works fine locally.

However on the test environment the Api routes are not matching a request, and instead are tried to be matched via the default MVC router. The default MVC route is registered at the end of our start up method.

I've triple checked the config transforms, even the deployed web.config to ensure there are no url rewrites getting in the way.

The requests are simple JSON requests.

Anyone have any pointers as to anything else that could cause the Api routes to be ignored on remote environments only?

Thanks

Comment: Try commenting out the other routing code.

Comment: Are you hosting in IIS or self hosting? If in IIS, there are various configuration points which could be affecting it such as URL rewrites. Try deploying to a new site instead of an existing one. Also there's a good nuget package called RouteDebugger which may offer some insight

Comment: @heymega Azure Websites - IIS.

Comment: @sallushan - Cheers, but it isn't the order of the routing, as the WebApi is registered first and works locally.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to old libraries in the bin folder on the remote server.

The lesson here is to make sure deleted files are also deleted in the build process, or to manually delete them.